# 404 after redirection with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

This is the .htaccess I have which is working fine on this level **mysite/new/**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(new)/(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Once I go into a new level **mysite/new/new-level** I get a 404. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: As always when debugging rewriteing rules: turn on the rewrite logging! There is little sense in trying to _guess_ what is going on. Take a look at the log, the engine tells you step by step what is going on...

Comment: Also if possible you should define rewriting rules in the main server configuration, not in `.htaccess` style files. Those files slow down the server considerably, are error prone and hard to debug. The only exceptions should be dynamic configuration and if you do not have access to the main server configuration.

Comment: @Labanino That code is working fine for a sub directory inside `/new/` folder. Can you provide more details of what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @anubhava. It is the same code you help me with before. It would be `mysite/new/`, and it works perfect but then there is another level `/new/portfolio/` with a bunch of images all grouped in a directory called 'portfolio'. So, when I click the link on the navigation to go to it I get a 404.

Comment: Can you open Firebug when you click on any of these links and see which link is generating 404? I suspect relative links for images/css/js might be the reason for this 404.